# Uniform circular motion, question on deriving the formula for the magnitude of the acceleration

Tags: centripetal-force

I'm reading Halliday, Resnick and Walker's Fundamentals of Physics and I am a little bit confused about something in the section on uniform circular motion(Chapter 4-5). I get all messed up on if they are referring to the vectors or their magnitude at certain points, their notation is very confusing. They use these the following similar triangles to get this equation

(Δv / v) = (Δr /r)
[image]

[image]

then solving for Δv and substituting into the formula for average acceleration

Average acceleration = Δv / Δt
[image]
[image]

I think the bold v indicates it is a vector and the weird looking v means it's magnitude, my first question was why they can use this to substitute into the Δv in the average acceleration equation which is the difference between two vectors. The book even points out that the relationship from the similar triangles is about their length so the magnitude of the vectors.
Upon further inspection, I see that the "a" in the equation is also not bold indicating magnitude but why could you use the same equation and just change it to equal the magnitude?

Is it something about the assumptions taken for uniform circular motion that are allowing these things that is tripping me up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In uniform circular motion, magnitude of tangential velocity is constant. But velocity overall is changing due to cenfripetal force.
By the definition of average acceleration,
$$\vec{A}_{avg}=\frac{\Delta\vec{v}}{\Delta{t}}$$
$\Delta\vec{v}$ is a vector, but in above case we are only dealing with magnitude.
So we can neglect the direction and substitute the magnitude to get
$$|A_{avg}|=\frac{|\vec{v}|.|\Delta{\vec{r}}|}{|\vec{r}|\Delta{t}}$$
When
$$\lim_{\Delta{t}\to0}|A_{avg}|=\frac{|\vec{v}|.|d{\vec{r}}|}{|\vec{r}|d{t}}$$
$$|A_{centripetal}|=\frac{|\vec{v}|.|\vec{v}|}{|\vec{r}|}$$

Comment: So explicitly is disregarding the direction from the equation something like this, Since the acceleration and velocity should have the same direction, we can cancel the direction from both sides?

Comment: No the direction of v and a are perpendicular

Comment: @foot good. We have just found a relationship between magnitude. it has nothing to do with directions. Also, $V$ is tangential and $A$ is radial , so both are perpendicular

Comment: @Alv I think you misunderstood me. I was trying to check my understanding of how we disregarded the direction from the average acceleration equation before substituting in what we got from the relationship. Sorry I did not worded it very clearly in my previous comment. Since I am wrong about the acc vector and vel vector having the same direction, I am even more confused as to why you could neglect  the direction in the average acceleration equation

Comment: @footgood If you look at vectors closely, you would see that $\Delta{\vec{v}}$, Points towards the centre and it should because acceleration is towards centre. It is important to know that $\Delta{\vec{v}}$ always points in the direction of applied acceleration. Since they have same direction, we can easily form relationships between magnitude and ignore direction.

Comment: @Alv Right, I got Δv and v messed up somehow in this whole mess. I think this cleared it up for me mostly. Thank you for answering my questions.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it something about the assumptions taken for uniform circular motion that are allowing these things that is tripping me up ?

I think it is the very confusing notation in the book that is tripping you up. You have to pay close attention to notice the difference between $\Delta \mathbf v$ (a vector) and $\Delta v$ (the magnitude of $\Delta \mathbf v$). The fact that $\mathbf v$ is treated as a vector but $r$ is not makes things even more confusing. As does the convention of writing the average acceleration vector as $\bar {\mathbf a}$ - do you have to guess that the bar means an average value ?

The underlying assumptions about the motion here are that the velocity has constant magnitude and makes a constant angle (in this case, a right angle) with the radius vector. This means that the $r, \Delta r$ triangle and the $\mathbf v, \Delta \mathbf v$ triangle are both isosceles triangles with the same apex angle $\theta$, and so are similar triangles. This allows the derivation of the relation

$\displaystyle \frac {\Delta v} v = \frac {\Delta r} r$

which can be written less confusingly as

$\displaystyle \frac {|\Delta \mathbf v|} {| \mathbf v |}= \frac {|\Delta \mathbf r |} {| \mathbf r |}$

You don't show the final step, but presumably it uses the fact that this is circular motion (rather than, say, spiral motion at constant speed) to derive

$\displaystyle \frac {|\Delta \mathbf r|}{\Delta t} = |\mathbf v|$

which is a constant, so finally

$\displaystyle |\mathbf a| = \frac {|\mathbf v|^2}{ |\mathbf r|}$

Comment: Thank you for writing it out for me like this, kind of wish the book went with this much easier to think about notation.

Answer (score 0):

> I get all messed up on if they are referring to the vectors or their
> magnitude at certain points, their notation is very confusing.

The book is using notation used by many Physicists.

In print some denote a vector as $\vec v$ whereas others denote a vector as $\bf v$ or even $v\,\hat {\bf v}$.
In the last case the $v$ is the magnitude ("length" of vector) and $\hat {\bf v}$ is the direction (unit vector).

When it comes to diagrams $\Large\xrightarrow{v}$ is the same as $\Large\xrightarrow{\bf v} $ where the arrow gives the direction of the vector ($\hat {\bf v}$), the label $v$ gives the magnitude (length) of the vector, and the label ${\bf{v}} (=v \hat {\bf v})$ is just a label with the implication that the magnitude of the vector is $v$.

So now let's look at the diagrams below.

Sequence $\bf 1$ shows information about position vectors with the last diagram showing magnitudes (lengths) of vectors and the relationship between them with $r_{\rm i}= r_{\rm f} = r$.

[image]

Sequence $\bf 2$ shows information about velocity vectors with the last diagram showing magnitudes (lengths) of vectors and the relationship between them with $v_{\rm i}= v_{\rm f} = v$.

To me the first two diagrams in a sequence convey the same information except that perhaps the symbols for the magnitudes are "formally" defined in the middle diagrams.

The derivation then assumes that the last triangles in each sequence are similar so $\dfrac{\Delta r}{r} = \dfrac{\Delta v}{v}$ and as $\Delta v \approx v\,\Delta \theta $ etc.